# How can i disable a field depending on the condition in Customization Epicor

Tags: c#, epicorerp, epicor

[image]

[image]

It said that 'edvRcvMisc' does not exist in the current context. How do i called a different table(RcvMisc) in RcvHead ?

I tried to do use BPM but it doesn't seem work as well and put different methods

Comment: SO suggests to post your Code as a formatted string, *Not as images: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

To continue down your implementation method, you need to instantiate your reference to `edvRcvMisc` as such:

```
EpiDataView edvRcvMisc = (EpiDataView)oTrans.EpiDataViews["RcvMisc"];
```

However, I strongly recommend using row rules. You can simply use the Epicor wizard to create a row rule for `RcvMisc.DocScrActualAmt`.  If there is not a field that can be used to indicate received status in `edvRcvMisc` and you do not want to denormalize the data with a BPM, then after you create the row rule you can change the row rule condition to a delegate, in which you can reference edvRcvHead data or perform any conditional function you wish.